# How retrieve current time of any country in my application?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to show the current time of any country. Suppose i want to find out current time of USA in Australia or i want to see current time of England in south Africa then how i retrieve current time of country? For that i was written an code but i does not worked,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
```

The above code does not given me correct time.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as time of USA or Australia. 
You have to use the correct timezone, and there are 4 on mainland USA, and 3 different timezones in australia.

To get the current time(string) of Melbourne, Berlin and Los Angeles you would use code like this:

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"]];
 NSString *melbourneTime = [df stringFromDate:now];
 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"]];
 NSString *berlinTime = [df stringFromDate:now];
 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"]];
 NSString *laTime = [df stringFromDate:now];
 NSLog(@"%@", melbourneTime);
 NSLog(@"%@", berlinTime);
 NSLog(@"%@", laTime);
```

The locale you've changed has influence on the format. For example the current time in melbourne in the en_US locale is `November 18, 2010 9:14:28 PM GMT+11:00` but in de_DE it is  `18. November 2010 21:14:28 GMT+11:00`

Comment: there is no matter how many timezone present in each country. i only want to current time using GMT format in any country?

Comment: sure it matters, there are 3 different "current times" in australia. and somebody has to make a choice which on to use.